# If I change my computer, how can I transfer my Stardew Valley save?

Tags: steam, stardew-valley

I would like to know that if I change my laptop can I still be playing the same Stardew Valley save that I have on my old laptop. Meaning, would I have the same save file directly connected to my Steam account or should I manually move it?

I looked everywhere to know whether I'd have to change it manually or not but haven't found an answer yet, hope it's an easy way to do that.

Comment: I don't quite agree with the duplicate. While it may seem like a duplicate from the title alone, the linked question is actually about transferring saves from one account to another; the "other computer" is just a bonus. This question is purely about transferring saves from one computer to another, while keeping the same account.

Comment: @Nolonar fair point about the duplicate, I must admit I did not realize transferring things to a different steam account AND a different PC might require different solutions from just moving between PCs :-)

Answer (score 12):

According to the [Steam Store page for Stardew Valley](https://store.steampowered.com/app/413150/Stardew_Valley/), the game supports Steam Cloud:
[image: Stardew Valley Steam Store page]

This means that as long as you are using the same Steam account and Steam Cloud is enabled, then **you don't need to do anything to transfer your save games**.

To check if Steam Cloud is enabled, and how to enable it if it isn't already: https://help.steampowered.com/en/faqs/view/68D2-35AB-09A9-7678#enabling

> ## How can I enable or disable The Steam Cloud
>
> The Steam Cloud can be toggled for individual games, or as a global Steam setting for all games. When Steam Cloud functionality of a game is disabled, all progress that would normally be saved via the cloud will only be saved locally on the machine where the progress was made.
>
> #### Individual games:
>
> - From the Steam Library, right click on any game and select Properties....
> - Under the General tab, the Cloud Synchronization setting can be toggled.
>
> #### All games:
>
> - From the Steam client Settings window, navigate to the Cloud tab.
> - Cloud can be enabled or disabled using the toggle next to Enable Steam Cloud Sync for applications that support it.

Comment: Can confirm: Me an my SO both have computers, theirs is on the TV. So sometimes I wanna play on the TV? I just close Stardew on my PC, wait maybe 5 minutes, and then I can load my game on the TV PC like if it was on the same PC.